# LocationMatch not matching like Location (Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache, locationmatch

I'm trying to understand what is going on with `LocationMatch`. Right now I have a `Location` similar to the following,

```
<Location "/context">
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass        http://example.com/context retry=0 connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
  ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/context
</Location>
```

Next I change only `Location` to `LocationMatch`, as below, and that works fine.

```
<LocationMatch "/context">
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass        http://example.com/context retry=0 connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
  ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/context
</LocationMatch>
```

But as soon as I introduce a regular expression this no longer matches correctly. For example, I want to match paths starting with `/context`,

```
<LocationMatch "^/context">
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass        http://example.com/context retry=0 connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
  ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/context
</LocationMatch>
```

I've been through the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) multiple times and can't seem to figure out why this regex doesn't match. I've also seen SOQs like [Apache LocationMatch matching urls starting with...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560733/apache-locationmatch-matching-urls-starting-with) but this regex doesn't work. I have a single `VirtualHost` on a vanilla Ubuntu apache2 install with this single `LocationMatch`. The entire conf file looks like this,

```
ProxyRequests off

PassEnv HTTPD_SERVER_NAME HTTPD_SERVER_ADMIN SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile ${SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE}
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE}

  Protocols h2 http/1.1
  ServerName ${HTTPD_SERVER_NAME}
  ServerAdmin ${HTTPD_SERVER_ADMIN}
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
  # Requires Apache 2.4.36 & OpenSSL 1.1.1
  SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
  SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves X25519:secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1
  # Older versions
  # SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  # Requires Apache >= 2.4
  SSLCompression off
  # Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
  SSLSessionTickets Off
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyVerify none
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  <LocationMatch "^/context">
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        http://example.com/context retry=0 connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/context
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is, should `<LocationMatch "^/context">` match URLs starting with `/context`? For example, `https://mydomain/context`? And if this should match, any idea what else could be interfering? I'm on version 2.4.41, but I've seen this behavior since at least 2.4.6. Thanks

Comment: Did you work out the problem? I'm hitting the same problem in Apache 2.4.29.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) on the `ProxyPass` directive:

> When used inside a `<Location>` section, the first argument is omitted
> and the local directory is obtained from the `<Location>`. The same will
> occur inside a `<LocationMatch>` section; **however, ProxyPass does not
> interpret the regexp as such, so it is necessary to use ProxyPassMatch
> in this situation instead.**

If I understand this correctly, it's not that your `<Location>` regex is invalid, it's just that your `<ProxyPass>` doesn't interpret it as a regex. So use `<ProxyPassMatch>` [instead](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch).

Also, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548631/how-can-locationmatch-and-proxypassmatch-be-combined) led me to some other pages which support the idea that `<LocationMatch>` and `<ProxyPass>` are incompatible with each other:

> As indicated by [this comment](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/121) and [this page](http://keita.flagship.cc/2013/06/04/locationmatch-and-proxypass/), I need to replace
> `ProxyPass` [with] `ProxyPassMatch` when using that inside a `LocationMatch` block